# insert chinese character into mysql through php and vba

Tags: php, mysql, vba

I tried still cannot input the Chinese character into the field..

The url looks like this:
http://xxx.xxx/AddCategory.php?CatID=0001&NameTC=石油&NameEN=Petroleum%20Gases&Random=1.401764E-02

**It works for URL but I am using VBA to run the url through php to update the mysql, it doesnt work. so maybe due to encoding problem in vba or php? Please advise!**

IN vba, I am using MSXLM2.XMLHTTP

```
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
        MsgBox "Error 0 has occured while creating a    MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest object"
    End If
```

CatID | CatName_TC | CatName_EN

Expected:

1001 | 工業 | Industrial

Results:

1001 | [Nothing]  | Industrial

I use Excel VBA to store these data into 3 variable and use web of php with parameter to insert into my mysql. I could not insert the Chinese character into the database. I could do it for CatID and CatName_EN, but add nothing on the field CatName_TC.

VBA Code:

```
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
            MsgBox "Error 0 has occured while creating a MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest object"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        If oHttp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "For some reason I wasn't able to make a MSXML2.XMLHTTP object"
            Exit Function
        End If

        'Open the URL in browser object
        On Error Resume Next
        oHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
        oHttp.Send
        oHttp.waitforresponse (10)
        GetWebHTML =

 oHttp.responseText
```

php Code:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("site", "name", "pass", "db");

    $CatID = isset($_GET['CatID']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["CatID"]) : NULL;
    $NameTC = isset($_GET['NameTC']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["NameTC"]) : NULL;
    $NameEN = isset($_GET['NameEN']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["NameEN"]) : NULL;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO AACategory (AACatID, CatNameTC, CatNameEN) VALUES (?,?,?)");

    // TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

    // "s" means the database expects a string
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $CatID, $NameTC, $NameEN);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The table could have been created with the default `latin1` charset instead of `utf8`. While it is not possible to convert existing values in CatNameTC column to utf8, you can alter the table for new inserts to use utf8 charset

```
ALTER TABLE AACategory CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: i found out that using url in browser is fine. so it won't be mysql problem. Through vba and run xmlhttp to pass the url to the web then cannot add. I guess it's encoding problem in vba or php. Please help